# Kuberneets - what is the "over" signifies in the age field

Tags: kubernetes

I had a log that looks like the following. What "over" in the age field signifies - some thing like "(x2 over 109s)"

```
Events:
  Type     Reason     Age                 From               Message
  ----     ------     ----                ----               -------
  Normal   Scheduled  110s                default-scheduler  Successfully assigned default/liveness-exec to minikube
  Warning  Unhealthy  60s (x3 over 70s)   kubelet, minikube  Liveness probe failed: cat: can't open '/tmp/healthy': No such file or directory
  Normal   Killing    60s                 kubelet, minikube  Container liveness failed liveness probe, will be restarted
  Normal   Pulling    30s (x2 over 109s)  kubelet, minikube  Pulling image "k8s.gcr.io/busybox"
  Normal   Pulled     28s (x2 over 105s)  kubelet, minikube  Successfully pulled image "k8s.gcr.io/busybox"
  Normal   Created    28s (x2 over 105s)  kubelet, minikube  Created container liveness
  Normal   Started    28s (x2 over 105s)  kubelet, minikube  Started container liveness
```

Comment: it signifies that the even occured `N` times over a period of `T` seconds. So `(x3 over 70s)` signifies that the event occured 3 times over a period of 70 seconds.

Comment: thanks, i didnt seem find this in the document, please send the link across

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Such numbers mean that the event occured `N` times over a period of `T` seconds. In your example `(x3 over 70s)` means that the event occured 3 times over a period of 70 seconds.  60 seconds ago liveness probe failed 3 times.

Looking at the `describePod` and `Describe` funcs from `staging/src/k8s.io/kubectl/pkg/describe/describe.go` should give you a better picture of it.

Take a look:  [kubectl-describe-sc](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/staging/src/k8s.io/kubectl/pkg/describe/describe.go)[debug-kubernetes-crashloopbackoff/](https://sysdig.com/blog/debug-kubernetes-crashloopbackoff/), [kubernetes-configure-liveness-and-readiness-probes](https://medium.com/@Alibaba_Cloud/kubernetes-configure-liveness-and-readiness-probes-588aa2cab90d).